# How to render loaded attributes from Catalog/Layer_View block

Tags: magento-1.8, blocks, product-attribute, layered-navigation

I am trying to get loaded product attributes from Layered navigation into listing page.

The below code is working fine if I print `$grid_labels[]`

When I am applying/selecting layered navigation filter, i am getting the following error :

**You cannot define a correlation name 'manufacturer_idx' more than once**

I am unable to identify why the block/attributes are loading twice.

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Catalog/Layer_View');
$_filters = $block->getFilters();
$grid_label = array();
$grid_attribute_code = array();
//echo "<pre>";
foreach ($_filters as $_filter) {
    if ($count = $_filter->getItemsCount()) {
        $attr = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('frontend_label', $_filter->getName());
        $attcodeobj = $attr->getData();
        $attrcode = $attcodeobj[0]['attribute_code'];
        if($attrcode!=''):
        $grid_label[] = array($attrcode => $_filter->getName());
endif;
        //$grid_attribute_code[] = $_filter->getLabel();
    }
}
```

Can any one help me out on this issue ?

Comment: Paste your layout xml.

Comment: @Nidheesh  I did not override any layout file. i am in product list.phtml by theme and trying to create $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Catalog/Layer_View');

Comment: What happens if you use ```$block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.leftnav');``` instead of createBlock()?

Comment: Why you want to create the catalog/layer_view block in listing page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the `You cannot define a correlation name 'attribute_idx' more than once` error is a well known issue.

It is caused by the fact that **the `catalog/layer_view` block is called twice.**

So depending on what you want to achieve you can either:

### Remove the original Magento left layered navigation

By adding the following to your `local.xml`

```
<remove name="catalog.leftnav" />
```

### Use the original Magento left layered navigation

Instead of creating the block so you'll have to replace:

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/layer_view');
```

With:

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.leftnav');
```

Comment: Thanks, perfect. It is working fine, but I need to call same block in Controller to filter from Ajax request. i have tried but not working. please tell me how can i call.

Comment: @krishnaijjadaati95Dev hard to do that in the comments feel free to create a new question I'll check it out

Comment: Sure , please check http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139552/how-to-csll-catalog-layer-view-block-in-controller-to-get-loaded-attributes