# How to csll Catalog/Layer_View block in controller to get loaded attributes

Tags: magento-1.8, blocks, layered-navigation

I want to use below code in controller but not working.

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('catalog.leftnav');
```

I used in phtml file [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138913/how-to-render-loaded-attributes-from-catalog-layer-view-block), it is working fine. but it is not working in controller.

Can any one help me on this issue.